# How to select and commit data to DB by chunks?

Tags: abap, opensql

I have written a code to get all records into internal table using select query, perform concatenation on it and update the DB from this internal table.

To improve performance how can I select specific number of records like 1000 records, process them and after updating the DB select next 1000 records and so on.

Here is my code

```
DATA: lv_index_table TYPE /ngv/b0tabnm,
      lref_tname     TYPE REF TO data.
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <lt_indx_table>  TYPE ANY TABLE,
               <lwa_indx_table> TYPE any.

    CALL METHOD /ngv/cl_bmtr_framework=>generated_table_get
      EXPORTING
        i_dtarea        = /ngv/if_bcon=>mc_data_area-index
      IMPORTING
        e_table         = lv_index_table      "here i get DB table name .
      EXCEPTIONS
        table_not_found = 1
        OTHERS          = 2.

    CHECK lv_index_table IS NOT INITIAL.

    CREATE DATA lref_tname TYPE TABLE OF (lv_index_table).
    ASSIGN lref_tname->* TO <lt_indx_table>.

    CHECK <lt_indx_table> IS ASSIGNED.
    SELECT * FROM (lv_index_table) INTO TABLE <lt_indx_table> UP TO 1000 ROWS.

 LOOP AT <lt_indx_table> ASSIGNING <lwa_indx_table>.
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'EXTID' OF STRUCTURE <lwa_indx_table> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_extid>).
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'MTRCT' OF STRUCTURE <lwa_indx_table> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_mtrct>).
  ASSIGN COMPONENT 'MSKVL' OF STRUCTURE <lwa_indx_table> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_mskvl>).

  CHECK <lv_extid> IS ASSIGNED AND <lv_mtrct> IS ASSIGNED AND <lv_mskvl> IS ASSIGNED.
  CONCATENATE <lv_extid> '_' <lv_mtrct>  INTO <lv_mskvl>.
ENDLOOP.
MODIFY (lv_index_table) FROM table <lt_indx_table>.
```

Comment: Isn't `SELECT UP TO. ENDSELECT.` what you're looking for? Alternatively you can use `OPEN CURSOR ... UP TO`. You have to be then also careful when making `COMMIT` after each package, the cursor is then invalidated.

Comment: actually ,i am writing code in abap and here lv_index_table db table is having lot of data . so using select query i want to get 1000 records from the table in local table lt_indx_table first and after performing concatenation operations and updating it in db table , i want to get next 1000 records and perform same operations . likewise it should continue.

Comment: `SELECT ... PACKAGE SIZE 1000 ... ENDSELECT.` or `OPEN CURSOR ...` and `FETCH ... PACKAGE SIZE 1000 ...`

Comment: unlikely you'll ever gain any performance by opening DB connection every 1000 records, it will be the opposite. Also look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49898103/shortest-notation-to-split-abap-internal-table-into-smaller-pieces

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions for your requirement. It depends your number of records, your system, database etc.

**If you have really huge data try cursors.**

You can process data in packages. That's not increase performance pretty much but it helps prevention of performance deterioration.

For detailed information check this links ([1](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapopen_cursor.htm) , [2](http://www.kerum.pl/infodepot/00016), [3](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/abapteamforum/select-v-s-open-cursor-t18773391.html)).

```
DATA s_cursor TYPE cursor.
DATA:it_mara TYPE TABLE OF mara.
OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD s_cursor FOR
SELECT * FROM mara.
DO.
  FETCH NEXT CURSOR s_cursor APPENDING TABLE it_mara PACKAGE SIZE 10.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.
"Your logic should be here..
 
"If you want to update database use CALL FUNCTION 'DB_COMMIT'
ENDDO.
CLOSE CURSOR s_cursor.
```